# How to add dynamically loaded icon to Alert in Flex?

Tags: image, apache-flex, icons, alert

I need to add my images/icons dynamically at runtime to my Flex GUI due to licencing reasons. So how can I add a dynamically loaded icon to an Alert? I use the following function

```
Alert.show(text:String = "", title:String = "", flags:uint = 0x4, parent:Sprite = null, closeHandler:Function = null, iconClass:Class = null, defaultButtonFlag:uint = 0x4, moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory = null):Alert
```

The problem is that the iconClass parameter is always an embedded Class object. Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RuntimeBitmapAssets.as` from [this post](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/runtime-icons-for-flex-components/):

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(loader.content).bitmapData;
var icon:Class = RuntimeBitmapAsset.getClass(bitmapData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! The problem with this solution is that everytime I open an Alert I have to execute another asynchronous call to add the Bitmap to `loader.content` (which can be pretty complex in a large application). In the meantime I found another similar solution: [IconUtility](http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42). The problem with this is the UIComponent parameter needed for the `IconUtility.getClass` function because I don't have a reference to my alert window in the static `Alert.show` function. Argh...

Comment: You can add some code to my or IconUtility class to adjust it to your needs or I will try to publish an update to my class in a few days.